# I am trying to generate a random #, convert to string, then assign suit based off of converted string

Tags: java

Needs to generate random # that randomly represents "suit;" and assigns the "suit" to suit property using the "suitValues[]" I am not sure how to do that.

```
public class Card
{
    int roll;
    String suit;
    String number;
    String[] numberValues = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A",};
    String[] suitValues = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

    public void createCard()
    {
        roll= 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((4-1)+1));
        String random ="";
        random = Integer.toString(roll);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `((4-1)+1)`, really?

Comment: This is a classic use case for an `enum`, by the way.

Comment: @EvertonAgner <<never trust math...>>

Comment: @EvertonAgner This is likely because the formula for getting an integer from `Math.random()` is `(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)`. Or at least that's my guess.

Comment: The `+1` is on the beginning of the statement: `roll = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((4-1)+1));`

Answer (score 4):

A common way to generate a "card" is to choose a random number between 0 and 51, and then calculating the suit as `number % 4` and the rank as `number / 4`.

So something like:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int card = rand.nextInt(52);
String suit = suitValues[card % 4];
String rank = numberValues[card / 4];
```

Note that this method is appropriate for generating a single, random card. If you want to generate a hand, or deal a deck, it's much simpler to instead randomly "shuffle" a full "deck" of numbers, since that ensures you don't "deal" the same card more than once. Determining which card has been dealt can still use the above method, though.

Comment: This is an elegant answer

Answer (score 0):

When modelling card games it's common to create a virtual deck, shuffle it and then draw the top card when dealing etc...

If you build that module it's easy to also draw just one "random" card from it.